# What are reliable ways of flattening out warped wood?

Tags: warp

I know about cutting a line on the concave side to loosen it, and then gluing in strips of wood once flat, and I know of using water on one side and then laying things on top to help it dry flat. Are there any other ways of making warped wood flat again?

Comment: Is this cupped? twisted?  bowed? crooked?

Comment: Are you referring to finished wood? (e.g., the surface of a table) Or are you referring to wood that's ready to be milled? If the latter, @Peter Grace's suggestion will work. Otherwise....I'm not sure.

Comment: What are your circumstances? Is it important to preserve the board's thickness?Width?

Answer (score 4):

Common wisdom is that if you have access to a jointer and planer, you will joint the board on the cupped side to flatten it, then use the planer to produce a smooth edge on the opposite side.  If you don't have a jointer, there are some jigs available that can attempt to replicate a jointer's function on just a planer.  If you don't have a planer, well, you'll be stuck using a hand plane to shave the warped portions off.

One thing I failed to mention is that one can also use a router to flatten a board; it seems a bit like a kludge but I wager many people have used this technique in absence of a jointer or planer.  The Wood Whisperer has a good video about this: [TWW 174 on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtkBZHLJyD0)

Comment: If you haven't built a "joint on your planer" carriage, the quick-and-dirty solution is to hot-glue a sacrificial scrap-wood runner along each side to keep the board stable during this process. Make sure both runners are flat against the bench when you glue them on, and they'll keep the main board from rocking. And, yeah, the router over a guide frame is another solution or you can go after it with hand planes. Warning: as you remove wood, the stresses may shift and the warp may change!